# What is this strange way of initializing IList<T> in Xamarin code base?

Tags: c#

I was looking at Xamarin code base (in this case `StackLayout` class) and I came with this strange line of code in C#, which I couldn't understand the syntax:

```
var layout = new StackLayout()
{
    Children =
    { // What is this!!!?
        new Label()
        {
            Text = "Hello",
        },
        new Entry()
        {
            Text = "Hi"
        },
    }
};
```

The code that I don't understand is the way it initializes the `Children` property. `Children` is a *get-only* property with **no setter**.

**Not only it is being initialized, but also there is no `new List<>` before `{`.**

Resharper can convert it to use `.Add()` instead of this initialization. So it seems it is not an initialization.

I think there's something added to C# which I'm not aware of!

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] of the code?

Comment: You`re not setting the ```Children``` property, you're adding items to the ```Children``` property. That's a simple way of adding items instead of using ```.Add``` for every item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a variation of the "initializer syntax" for collections, valid when initializing property values in a new instance.

The initializer syntax in general allows assigning values to properties when using the `new` operator. Then, in that context, the collection initializer syntax maps an assignment to a sequence of calls to an `Add()` method (if present, which it is in this case).

This isn't unique to Xamarin. Here's a simple C# example:

```
public class Class1
{
    public IList<string> List { get; } = new List<string>();

    public static Class1 M()
    {
        return new Class1
        {
            List =
            {
            "foo", "bar"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide the documentation which describes how we can initialize list properties within an object initializer  like this? I've found this official document which has not mentioned this feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer

Comment: You were so close! See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers, the parent page to the one you were looking at. Note in particular the final example, that really drives home the concept that _all_ you need for the collection initializer syntax to work is that the type implements `IEnumerable`, and that it has a suitable `Add()` method. Since the actual left-side value isn't itself being modified, it works even with read-only properties and fields.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to run your code with these classes:

```
public class StackLayout
{
    public object[] Children;
}

public class Label
{
    public string Text;
}

public class Entry
{
    public string Text;
}
```

If I do that I get the following error:

> CS1061 'object[]' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'object[]' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

If I change it to this:

```
public class StackLayout
{
    public List<object> Children;
}
```

Then I get the error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

So finally I do this:

```
public class StackLayout
{
    public List<object> Children = new List<object>();
}
```

That works.

So the syntax you've shown is shorthand for calling an `.Add(...)` method.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Feature of C# 6 and the collection initializer Syntax. In short: If the Item does have an Add-Method than the Compiler will use it to initialize the Collection. See [Extension Add methods in collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#extension-add-methods-in-collection-initializers) in the C# 6 release notes.

Comment: Could you change the url to English version?

Answer (score 0):

Not only for IList:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Person
        {
            Name = "Mark",
            Address = //<<<<<<<< HERE
            {
                Number = 3,
                Street = "Long street"
            }
        };
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Btw, could somebody tell me the name of this C# feature?

Comment: "Collection Initializers". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Comment: Exactly, what is the name of this feature?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Which part of it talks about this!? I can not find anything like this!

Comment: @PeterDuniho In my code, it is not a collection, just a property. I know about collection initializer.

Comment: @Fanliver: ah, sorry...I glossed over your code, making the assumption you were trying to address the question that was asked. In your case, it's "Object Initializers". Same doc page.

Comment: And even if it did compile this is only tangentially related to the question.